# how to increment value of a column up to specific range for values in other column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The existing table is like:

```
tmc         speed
ABC         55
DEF         55
```

I want to create a table like the following one using the existing table in SQL Server 2008:

```
tmc            speed
ABC            55
ABC            56
ABC            57
ABC            58
ABC            59
ABC            60
DEF            55
DEF            56
DEF            57
DEF            58
DEF            59
DEF            60
```

The code I developed is not showing me the exact result I want. Any help will be highly appreciated.

code I used to solve the problem is:

```
; WITH mycte AS 
( SELECT [tmc_code], [speed] FROM table_1 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT [tmc_code], [speed]+1 FROM table_1 WHERE [speed]+1 <=60 ) 
SELECT [tmc_code], [speed] FROM mycte
```

Comment: code I used to solve the problem is: ; WITH mycte AS
(
 SELECT [tmc_code], [speed] FROM table_1
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT [tmc_code], [speed]+1 FROM table_1
 WHERE [speed]+1 <=60
)
SELECT [tmc_code], [speed] FROM mycte

Comment: "The code I developed is not showing me the exact result I want" --- let's start with it may be?

Comment: What is the logic here? What is the process to get from the existing table to the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
;WITH mycte AS (
  SELECT 1 n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM mycte WHERE n < 100
)
SELECT tmc_code, speed + n - 1 speed
  FROM table1 CROSS JOIN mycte
 WHERE mycte.n BETWEEN 1 AND 6
 ORDER BY tmc_code, speed
```

Output:

```
| TMC_CODE | SPEED |
|----------|-------|
|      ABC |    55 |
|      ABC |    56 |
|      ABC |    57 |
|      ABC |    58 |
|      ABC |    59 |
|      ABC |    60 |
|      DEF |    55 |
|      DEF |    56 |
|      DEF |    57 |
|      DEF |    58 |
|      DEF |    59 |
|      DEF |    60 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d556c/9)** demo

Comment: thank you so much.......it helped a lot.........I used the same idea to work with few other variables........

Answer (score 0):

Consider a persisted numbers table, [it can have many uses](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable), including your present problem.

With a numbers table, you could do the following:

```
SELECT
  t.tmc_code,
  speed = t.speed + n.Number
FROM table_1 AS t
INNER JOIN numbers AS n ON n.Number BETWEEN t.speed AND t.speed + 5
;
```